# Flutter skip firebase signin when creating new user with email and password

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I m recently coding an app, where i use firebase as backend.

I created a method to sign up with firebase but I dont want it to sign in with the new user recently created. Is it possible to keep firebase auth signed in with the current user who adds the new user?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to keep firebase auth signed in with the current user
> who adds the new user?

With the clients SDKs/plugins (FlutterFire, JavaScript SDK, etc.) this is not possible.

One way is to [use the Admin SDK to create your users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users). For example you can create a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which creates the users and which is [called by the end-user from the front-end](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage).

I've written an [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) that details the entire approach with the corresponding code.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, did you had time to look at the proposed solution?